# Transform certain integrands so that they involve a single square root rather than two.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, transformation

I need--in pursuit of my problem https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342446/perform-certain-constrained-integrations-over-an-ordered-subsection-of-a-3-simpl --to integrate
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(x+1) \left(2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2\right)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(1-2 x) \left(2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2\right)}
\end{equation}
over $x \in [\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{4}]$, as well as
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{-x \left(x+2 \sqrt{-x (2 x-1)}-1\right)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(2 x-1) \left(x+2 \sqrt{-x (2 x-1)}-1\right)}
\end{equation}
over $x \in [\frac{1}{8} \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right),\frac{1}{6}]$.

I am rather confident--along the order of the answer of Vasily Mitch to [Can a certain series of integrals over $[0,\frac{1}{16}]$ be solved using integration-by-parts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228259/can-a-certain-series-of-integrals-over-0-frac116-be-solved-using-integr) -- that these four integrands can each be simplified so that they involve only one square root, rather than their present two, thus (and products of $x^n$ with them) becoming integrable, but would like a "second opinion".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would up employing for my indicated original problem 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342446/perform-certain-constrained-integrations-over-an-ordered-subsection-of-a-3-simpl the five transformations,
\begin{equation}
\left\{\sqrt{(x+1) \left(2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2\right)}\to \sqrt{-2
   x^2-x+1}+x+1,\sqrt{(1-2 x) \left(2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2\right)}\to \sqrt{-2
   x^2-x+1}-2 x+1,\sqrt{(2 x-1) \left(x+2 \sqrt{-x (2 x-1)}-1\right)}\to -\sqrt{x-2
   x^2}-2 x+1,\sqrt{-x (2 x-1)^2 \left(x+2 \sqrt{-x (2 x-1)}-1\right)}\to 2 x^2+\sqrt{-8
   x^4+12 x^3-6 x^2+x}-x,\sqrt{(x+1) (2 x-1)^2 \left(2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2\right)}\to
   -2 x^2+\sqrt{-8 x^4+4 x^3+6 x^2-5 x+1}-x+1\right\}.
\end{equation}

This allowed me to check the earlier calculation to high numerical accuracy 
(0.0036582630543034854603976004088368)--indicating the validity of the five transformations--but the last transformation still left me with an integrand 
$\sqrt{-8 x^4+4 x^3+6 x^2-5 x+1}$, I could not integrate--when multiplied by powers of $x$--over $x \in [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3}]$. (So, I'm still frustrated in achieving my original goal.) Also, $\sqrt{-8 x^4+4 x^3+6 x^2-5 x+1}=\sqrt{(-x-1) (2 x-1)^3}$, but this doesn't seem to help.)

Also, I developed a "fun" way of deriving the rules. I computed arrays of length  50, into which I put the values of the left-hand sides (the functions to be transformed) for $x=1,\ldots,50$. I, then, got the real and imaginary parts of the resultant values, and used the Mathematica FindSequenceFunction command on the real parts and on the imaginary parts squared.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{(1+x)(1-2x)^3} &=& (1-2x)\sqrt{\frac{9}{8}-2\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\\
&=&{3\over 2\sqrt{2}}(1-2x)\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4x+1}{3}\right)^2}\ .
\end{eqnarray}
The integral of this can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions by substituting $\ x={3\sin t -1\over 4}\ $.

Comment: Thanks lonza leggiera.  I'll implement this. Will this substitution also succeed if the l.h.s. is multiplied by powers of x--which is the situation I have?

Comment: Yes. Your integrand will be expressible as a polynomial in $\ \sin t\ $ and $\ \cos t\ $.  Methods for integrating products of powers of $\ \sin\ $ and $\ \cos\ $ can be found in any comprehensive calculus textbook. [Here's](https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-TrigonometIntegrals_Stu.pdf) one example.

Comment: Using Rubi with *Mathematica* for $\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{3}} x^2 \sqrt{(-x-1) (2 x-1)^3} \, dx$ gets you $\frac{73513}{622080}+\frac{513 \tan ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{2}\right)}{1024 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{281 \sqrt{5}+1539 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{5}\right)}{3072 \sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you're right.
\begin{eqnarray}
2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2&=&
2\sqrt{(1-2x)(1+x)} -x+2\\
&=&2\sqrt{(1-2x)(1+x)} +1+x+1-2x\\
&=& \left(\sqrt{1-2x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)^2\ .
\end{eqnarray}
So
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{(x+1)\left(2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2\right)}\\
=\sqrt{(1-2x)(1+x)}& +(1+x)
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{(1-2x) \left(2 \sqrt{-2 x^2-x+1}-x+2\right)}\\
=\sqrt{(1-2x)(1+x)}& +(1-2x)
\end{eqnarray}
Also,
\begin{eqnarray}
1+2 \sqrt{x(1-2x)}-x&=& 2 \sqrt{x(1-2x)} + x + 1-2x\\
&=& \left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-2x}\right)^2\ . 
\end{eqnarray}
So
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{x \left(1+2 \sqrt{x(1-2x)}-x\right)}&=& x+\sqrt{x(1-2x)}\ ,
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{(1-2x) \left(1+2 \sqrt{x(1-2x)}-x\right)}\\
=(1-2x)&+\sqrt{x(1-2x)}\  .
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Looks fabulous--thanks very much! Will do some implementing/checking, and then likely accept it.